# Which version of Rhino Mocks gets the most benefit from C#3.0 or later versions of C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, extension-methods, rhino-mocks

I want to know which version of Rhino Mocks gets the most benefit of C# 3.0 features like lambda expressions, extension methods etc.

I believe to make use of those features of C# would ease the writing of the unit tests especially for arrange-act-assert pattern.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest one?

Comment: Rhino Mocks is excellent, but it's worth taking a look at MOQ as well as it was written from the ground up to use generics/lambdas etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAA syntax was introduced since 3.5 release:

[Rhino Mocks 3.5 Beta Released](http://ayende.com/blog/3319/rhino-mocks-3-5-beta-released)

> The biggest new feature is the new AAA syntax, which you can read
>   about in the relevant post, but we had a few other new things as well.
>   Note that this release if for .Net 3.5 only. Rhino Mocks 3.5 RTM will
>   be for .Net 2.0 and 3.5, but I am focusing on the capabilities that I
>   can get from the 3.5 platform at the moment

Useful links:

- [AAA syntax examples](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer - the latest version of Rhino Mocks
You can check builds here: http://builds.hibernatingrhinos.com/builds/Rhino-Mocks